Changing the arguments when substituting a function
After a page of sympy manipulations I get and expression involving LambertW, but the answer given is for the zeroth branch cut.  I can tell that I wanted the -1 branch.  So, I'd like to change every occurrence of LambertW(y) into LambertW(y, -1).real, where y is an arbitrary sympy expression (that is different in each instance), in a set of expressions that are large enough so that doing it by hand is error prone.
There must be an easy way.

OK, there is a simple way of doing this.  sympy has a Lambda function that is functionally equivalent to Python core lambda function but designed to work correctly with sympy.  In particular, it doesn't choke on automatic simplifications and the like.  I was trying a bunch of variations of the Python lambda functions for def.
The solutions is:
from sympy.functions.elementary.exponential import LambertW
from sympy import Lambda

ySym = Symbol('y', positive=True)
LambertW(1 - ySym).subs(LambertW, Lambda(ySym, LambertW(ySym,-1)))

The result is:
W_{-1}(1 - y)

Does anyone know how to format math in this forum, it just works like LaTeX in other forums.

There is no LaTeX formatting on Stack Overflow. Other Stack Exchange sites have that functionality.
